# Python project in DBFS

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

My company is moving from on-prem to Azure, we are storing the project in `dbfs:/src/`. I'm developing my code in databricks notebooks and converting the file to .py and the final execution is done through azure data factory pipeline python activity.

**suppose my folder structure is like this:**

```
dbfs:/src
      |-- __init__.py
      |-- common
          |-- __init__.py
          |-- util.py
      |-- main.py
```

**main.py:**

```
# what I want to do
from common import util
# ImportError: attempted relative import with no parent package

# what I'm doing
spark.SparkContext.addPyFile("/dbfs/src/common/util.py")
import util
```

Is there a way to exactly replicate a python env kind of thing or I should be using `addPyFile()`

Comment: what we usually do is call databricks notebook directly in ADF instead of python activity and inside activity if we want some functions from other notebooks we use %run to execute and import the required functions so any specific reason you want to keep using python activity instead of notebook activity

Comment: don't know the exact reason but we are asked to use only python activities not notebooks. (I'm a fresher and this is my first project)

Comment: It is a python project previously, but now the execution is done in azure data factory pipeline through python activity. where I'm unable to use relative imports. It is okay for executing in pipeline but for unit testing I'm facing issues like spark is not defined, dbfs://path is not found.

Comment: So this python being run as databricks activity or custom activity and azure batch?

Comment: it's a databricks activity